# Trying to make a menu with buttons; program crashes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The title is pretty self explanatory.  I am currently trying to make a cocos2d menu and it compiles flawlessly however it crashes right before fully launching and my log reads this...

```
+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'
```

I don't know what this means here is my code though

```
    // Standard method to create a button
    CCMenuItem *Earth = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"1.png" 
                                               selectedImage:@"1.png" 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(loadLevel:)];
    Earth.position = ccp(160, 0);

    CCMenuItem *Mars = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"2.png" 
                                              selectedImage:@"2.png" 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(loadLevel:)];
    Mars.position = ccp(160, 240);

    CCMenuItem *Moon = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"3.png" 
                                              selectedImage:@"3.png" 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(loadLevel:)];
    Moon.position = ccp(160, 480);

    CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:Earth, Mars,Moon, nil];
    [myMenu setPosition:ccp(160,240)];
    [self addChild:myMenu z:0];
```

After adding this my program began to crash.  Thanks for any help guys you are the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement loadLevel like this

```
-(void) loadLevel:(NSObject*) sender
{
}
```

Comment: ok now that I have all these buttons in a menu how can I drag the view to find the button because not all the buttons fit on the screen... Just like the angry birds level select